# Slurm divide work into more parts than concurrency degree

Tags: slurm

I have a large task that I'd like to divide up into parts and run in parallel using slurm. Specifically, I'd like to divide the work up into more parts than can run concurrently on my system with the resources that I'd like to allocate. The basic idiom I have in mind is to call `sbatch`, dividing the work into `k` (greater than some `N` maximum number of concurrent tasks) parts, and have slurm queue tasks until there are resources available to run them. Concretely, imagine I have some file where each line represents a piece of work to be done, and I'd like to divide that work into 1000 pieces, running some single-threaded script to process each piece on a cluster with a total of 128 cpus. My current sbatch script looks something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=128

split -a 4 -d -n l/1000 workfile work_part_

PART_ID=0000 srun --ntasks=1 ./do_work.sh &
PART_ID=0000 srun --ntasks=1 ./do_work.sh &
.
.
.
PART_ID=0999 srun --ntasks=1 ./do_work.sh &

wait
```

Where `do_work.sh` uses `PART_ID` to find the appropriate work part file to work from, and writes out some output part file. When I try to run this, I get a bunch `Resource temporarily unavailable` errors and many of the job steps show as 'Cancelled' or 'Cancelled by <my user id>'. I feel like this should be some kind of common use-case, but I can't puzzle out how to get slurm to allocate the resources properly in a single job. I know that I could just perform the split outside of slurm and queue up 1000 separate jobs with `srun` but I'd prefer to have them all grouped together under one job with `sbatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific use case, `srun` needs the `--exclusive` keyword otherwise it will inherit the full allocation even if you specify `--ntasks=1`.

Note that in recent version of slurm `--exclusive` was deprecated by `--exact` and that in even more recent versions, if you specify `--cpus-per-task` explicitly on the `srun` line, `--exact` will be implied.

You will see in the logs that all `srun` will start, but only 128 of them will do the work, while the others will complain that resources are temporarily unavailable until some other terminate and free up resources.

Note that you can use a Bash loop or the GNU Parallel tool to avoid writing explicitly all steps in the submission script.